# VIM Editor: How to do auto formatting in VIM?

Tags: vim, formatting

I am new to VIM, so still learning. The thing I wanna do is instead of using tabs, I wanna to use 2 spaces to replace A tab. I wanna apply this format to my entire java code. How would I do it? Thanks!

Updated I used this following and it worked

```
:%s/\t/  /
```

Comment: Do you mean "I do not want to indent with ASCII TAB characters?"? That is the nearest I can guess from the word "tapping".

Comment: You might find the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998/tabs-and-spaces-in-vim) useful.

Comment: The way to indicate that your question has been answered is to accept an answer (you can post and accept your own answer if you like). Adding "[SOLVED]" to the title is just noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of replace tabs with spaces.  If you want to use search-and-replace, you need the `:s` command.  Try typing ":help :s" for help.  You'll find that the following works:

```
:%s/<ctrl-v><tab>/  /g
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a builtin `:retab`

You can also use `gg=G` to reindent the entire source file.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `=` command to format code, if you indent a line with two spaces, the following lines may be indented with 2 spaces if you use the `=<movement>` command on them.